# Onchange of dropdownlist containing javascript returning false doesnot stop calling the dropdownlist _SelectedIndexChange

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have one dropdownlist placed in a repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCommissionDistribution" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCommissionDistribution_ItemDataBound"
                OnItemCreated="rptCommissionDistribution_ItemCreated" OnItemCommand="rptCommissionDistribution_ItemCommand">

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSplitType" runat="server" DataTextField="SplitTypeName" OnChange="return  confirm_change(this.id,this.value);" DataValueField="SplitTypeId" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkOverride" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnChange="setdirty();" />
</asp:Repeater>
```

Placed javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_change(id, value) {
    var dropdownid = id;
    var checkboxid = dropdownid.replace("ddlSplitType", "chkOverride");

    if (document.getElementById(checkboxid).checked == true) {          
        alert('clicked');
        return true;
    }
    else {            
        alert('not clicked');
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

on .cs page we have

```
protected void ddlSplitType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
DropDownList ddlSplitType = sender as DropDownList;
RepeaterItem rptCommissionDistributionItem = ddlSplitType.Parent as RepeaterItem;       
CommissionDistributionController objCommissionDistributionController = new CommissionDistributionController();
***-----------And all Stuff--------------***
}
```

***What I want is that when javascript "returns false;" than .cs page code "ddlSplitType_SelectedIndexChanged" should not get called and when javascript "returns true;" that time my cs page code "ddlSplitType_SelectedIndexChanged" should get called.***

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. (Since you have your DDL in a repeater you have to find it first)

Code behind

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //Only if the event argument was from my drop down add the event
                if (Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].Equals("ddlSplitTypechange"))
                    ddlSplitType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    ddlSplitType.Attributes.Add("onchange", "confirm_change();");
            }
        }
        protected void ddlSplitType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

In your JS

```
function confirm_change(id, value) {
    var dropdownid = id;
    var checkboxid = dropdownid.replace("ddlSplitType", "chkOverride");

    if (document.getElementById(checkboxid).checked == true) {          
        alert('clicked');
    __doPostBack("ctl00$MainContent$ddlSplitType","ddlSplitTypechange");
    }
    else {            
        alert('not clicked');
        return false;
    }

    }
```

You can as well try this

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSplitType" runat="server" 
 AutoPostBack="true" onchange="javascript: return confirm_change();" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSplitType_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**ASP.NET:**

```
<asp:DropDownList
    ID="ddlTest1"
    runat="server"
    onChange="if (!jsFunction()) return false;"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTest1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function jsFunction() 
{
    return confirm("Yes or No?");
}
```

**Code Behind (C#):**

```
protected void ddlTest1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do Something
}
```